# Help installing PMD Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, redhat, pmd

I am trying to install PMD onto my Eclipse Helios installation. I follow the usual instructions to use the 'Install New Software' feature within Eclipse. All seems to go swimmingly and the installation completes. After restarting Eclipse, the option to use PMD is not there as expected (by right-clicking on a project).

Could someone advise on any steps I may have missed? Eclipse is the 20100617-1415 version installed on Red Hat running KDE.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about PMD but try FindBugs as an alternative.  I've heard their false-positive rate is much lower.

Answer (score 4):

Either the PMD plugin had an error on installation, or there was a problem when trying to start the plugin up.  Either way, there should be something in your error log.

I'd first check there to see if something relevant in the log (open the `Error log` view).  If not, then you can check to see if the plugin is actually installed.  Click on Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> plugins and look for PMD.

If it is installed, then try uninstalling and reinstalling it.  If the PMD plugin is not installed, then something failed.

Make sure that your eclipse/ directory is writable for the current user (while not a hard requirement, many plugins do need this for some reason).

Comment: can you please help me on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398629/error-while-installing-pmd-in-eclipse

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible to install PMD from the Eclipse Marketplace.
Only way: Help > Install New Software... > Add... > http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have installed eclipse-pmd instead of PMD. It'll be avalible only in the project's properties option.

You can better try to install from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/
But, make sure the Window-Preferences-General-Network Connection is "Direct" and "Native".

And restart. You'll surely find the PMD in preferences. I did for Keplar and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To install the PMD plugin for Eclipse:

- Start Eclipse and open a project
- Select "Help"->"Software Updates"->"Find and Install"
- Click "Next", then click "New remote site"
- Enter "PMD" into the Name field and
  "http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/"
  into the URL field
- Click through the rest of the dialog boxes to install the plugin

To configure PMD, select "Windows"->"Preferences", then select PMD.

To run PMD, right-click on a project node and select "PMD"->"Check code with PMD".

For more info refer [LINK](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/integrations.html#eclipse)