# Error while installing PMD in eclipse

Tags: pmd

While installing PMD in eclipse Luna, i am getting some error like `could not find jar` even after jar is inside the zip file.

what i ve done is, downloaded the zip file of PMD eclipse file from

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/latest/download?source=files
```

and in eclipse > Help > install new software >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To install the PMD for Eclipse plugin:

In Eclipse, click on Help -> Install New Software...

Click on Add..

Enter the following: Name: PMD for Eclipse Update Site URL: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/ and click OK.

You should see PMD for Eclipse

Select the checkbox next to it and click Next >.

You'll need to accept the license and confirm you want to install a plugin that is not digitally signed. Go ahead and install it anyway.

Restart eclipse.

It will work.

Comment: I have added enough details to make it useful.